# How to change sublime text auto-completion brace style to cuddle

Tags: sublimetext, curly-braces

Sublime text autocompletes with the following style

```
if (/* condition */)
{
    /* code */
}
```

However, I prefer the braces to be "cuddled" like this:

```
if (/* condition */){
    /* code */
}
```

Is there a way to change that?

**Note**

- I found this post from 6 years ago but I hope that now we have a way to avoid going through all the snippets manually.
- I wanna change the auto-completion. I don't want to change everything with regex.

Comment: There isn't a global way to do this with a setting or something. You'd need to edit all of the snippets for the language(s) you're using.

Comment: there's an open issue with a suggestion of how this could be implemented to make it easy to change: https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/131

Comment: Another option is to adopt an opinonated code formatter such as Prettier for JS. Then you can have it reformat on save, and you just never think about it again. I appreciate that this won't work for everyone, but it does side-step the need for the question.